# Screen Reader stops at every paragraph/header

Tags: html, accessibility, dreamweaver, screen-readers, nvda

I’m extremely new to coding (as in- learning it on the job).

I’m creating an HTML document to be read by a screen reader. I’m currently using NVDA to test-read but do not know what the client will be using.

My code is all HTML, no CSS, with basic `<p>` tags. NVDA will read between each `<p>` tag and then stop. I have to move the mouse to the next paragraph for it to keep reading. This did not happen on any websites I visited using NVDA.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your lack of understanding of how a screen reader works.  The first thing you should do with NVDA is turn off the mouse tracking (Ins+N > Preferences > Settings > Mouse > uncheck mouse tracking checkbox).  You can use the up/down keys to walk the DOM and read each element individually.  Use Ins+downarrow to read the entire page.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to screen readers and am unable to talk to the client who uses one so it's been tricky.

Your suggestion helped. I have a tagged PDF made in InDesign. The screen reader stops in seemingly random places (in the middle of a line/sentence) and I have to press the down arrow for it to continue.

In InDesign I have each paragraph tagged individually, rather than each section under a heading. Do you have any suggestions on a way to fix this? Or is this normal?

Comment: That’s normal. Screen readers typically buffer the text. If you use Ins+downarrow, it should read everything.